# Dice Roller with Python PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How to set up image with random number I mean If 1 comes up then 1dot image will load. please give me a solution.It generating numbers and loading image but i have no idea how to make a logic for every time when I press roll it will change the image according to random number 1 to 6.

```
import random
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication,QMainWindow, QPushButton,QTextEdit,QLabel,QFileDialog)
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setFixedSize(400,400)
        self.setWindowTitle("Simple Dice roller")
        
        self.button = QPushButton('Roll', self) #button connection
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.clickmethod) #methodclicked button  connection
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.imageview) # buttonimageview connection
        self.msg =  QTextEdit(self) #for showing text while clicking on button in box
        
        self.msg.resize(100,32)
        self.msg.move(100,100)
        
        self.button.resize(100,32)
        self.button.move(50,50)
        self.imageview()
       
    def clickmethod(self):
        ran = str(random.randint(1,6))
        self.msg.setText(ran)

    def imageview(self):
        label = QLabel(self)
        label.move(100, 110)
        label.setFixedSize(500, 300)
        pixmap = QPixmap(r'S:\Dice sumilator\diceimage\1dot.jpg')
        #pixmap = QPixmap(r'S:\Dice sumilator\diceimage\2dots.jpg')
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
                        
if __name__ == "__main__":    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Diceroll = MainWindow()
    Diceroll.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a cheap/easy way of making this work using the QGraphicScene Widget.
It creates an area to display an image and updates it based on a if statement.

UPDATE: Took away erroneous statement according to my peers.

```
import random
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QTextEdit, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsPixmapItem, QGraphicsView)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("Simple Dice roller")

        self.button = QPushButton('Roll', self)  # button connection
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.clickmethod)  # methodclicked button  connection
        self.msg = QTextEdit(self)  # for showing text while clicking on button in box

        self.msg.resize(100, 32)
        self.msg.move(100, 100)

        self.button.resize(100, 32)
        self.button.move(50, 50)

        self.graphicsView = QGraphicsView(self)

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.pixmap = QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self.scene.addItem(self.pixmap)
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)
        self.graphicsView.resize(100, 100)
        self.graphicsView.move(200, 200)

    def clickmethod(self):
        ran = str(random.randint(1, 6))
        self.msg.setText(ran)
        if ran == '1':
            print(ran)
            img = QPixmap('dice1.png')
            self.pixmap.setPixmap(img)
        elif ran == '2':
            print(ran)
            img = QPixmap('dice2.png')
            self.pixmap.setPixmap(img)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Diceroll = MainWindow()
    Diceroll.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The note about the QLabel is actually incorrect. There are only 2 aspects that have to be taken into account with QLabel: when using *rich* text (as explained in the [issues section of the layout documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#layout-issues)) since there are size adjustment problems, and when using [`setScaledContents(True)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#scaledContents-prop) when using an image, since the aspect ratio is ignored. Besides that, there are really no downsides, especially in this case where no ratio/size is specified and no layout management is involved.

Comment: Also, QLabel is **not** "the only widget that work[s] differently from the rest". Some examples: QStackedWidget/QStackedLayout (the `minimumSizeHint()` depends on the maximum page sizes), QPushButton (has a size constraint), QComboBox (depends on the `sizeAdjustPolicy`), QSplitter (based on the displayed widgets' hints). There's a reason for which the [`controlType()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#controlType) function of QSizePolicy exists.

Comment: Thank you guyz Its helped me a lot and both the answers are working. Thankyou again for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>What they point out in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65291680/6622587) is incorrect, in this case QGraphicsPixmapItem and QLabel have the same capacity since they both serve to display QPixmaps. There is no difference here in when to difficulty or other things that are incorrectly noted.</sub>

If you want to choose images randomly then you must create a list of the images and use random.choices to get the image randomly and update the QPixmap that QLabel shows:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("Simple Dice roller")

        self.button = QPushButton("Roll", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.clickmethod)
        self.msg = QTextEdit(self)

        self.msg.resize(100, 32)
        self.msg.move(100, 100)

        self.button.resize(100, 32)
        self.button.move(50, 50)
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.move(100, 110)
        self.label.setFixedSize(500, 300)

    def clickmethod(self):
        images = [
            r"S:\Dice sumilator\diceimage\1dot.jpg",
            r"S:\Dice sumilator\diceimage\2dots.jpg",
        ]
        random_image = random.choices(images)
        pixmap = QPixmap(random_image)
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
```